# Double click listener on a tree viewer

Tags: java, swt

I have a selection changed listener on a tree viewer wherein If I single click the items in the tree depending on the selected item the combo viewer's selection changes accordingly.

Now I need to implement a double-click functionality on the same tree so that the tree expands and collapses hiding the functionality of the selection changed listener. Right now the priority is on the selection changed listener so even if I add a double-click listener to the same tree the selection change event gets triggered. Is there any way I can have both selection change listener(for selection change events) and Double-click listener(to expand/collapse tree items) on the same tree?

Code for IDoubleClickListener

```
public class TreeViewerDblClkListener implements IDoubleClickListener {

@Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
    Object obj = event.getSource();
    if (obj instanceof TreeViewer) {
        TreeViewer viewer = (TreeViewer) obj;
        ISelection selection = viewer.getSelection();
        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            Object item = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
            if (viewer.getExpandedState(item)) {
                viewer.collapseToLevel(item, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
            } else {
                viewer.expandToLevel(item, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It does throw an assertion failed exception.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getExpandedState(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1202)
at com.commons.viewers.TreeViewerDblClkListener.doubleClick(TreeViewerDoubleClickListener.java:20)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
```

Is anyone aware of what is happening here?

Comment: No, I think the selection changed event will always fire. What are you doing in the selection listener that should not be done for double click?

Comment: In the selection change listener I just set the selected tree item to a combo box and display few important variable details. So if selection changed event always fires it's relatively fine with me but when I add a double click listener to the same tree the tree items do not expand/collapse. Is there a workaround for this issue? Can I have both selection changed listener and Double-click listener on the same Tree?

Comment: You can have both, there should be no problem. Show your code for the `IDoubleClickListener`.

Comment: So when I do treeviewer.addDoubleClickListener(new TreeViewerDblClkListener) and run the code and double click on the tree items it throws an AssertionFailed Exception

Comment: @user3354299 Where does it throw this exception?

Comment: I'm so sorry there was a bug elsewhere in the code. I have corrected it and the expand/collapse works fine. Now is there a way I could get the type of event that is being generated so that the selection changed listener does not fire when I double click? It should only fire when I single click. Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to detect that a double click event is coming in the selection event.

Comment: I have edited my question above. It does throw an AssertionFailedException only in one particular class where I have a selection change listener for mouseDown event as well as a double click listener for the same tree. Is there a conflict between the two or anything else that's happening here. I tried a lot but could not get rid of this exception. I can't even understand what it means. Can someone please help me here.

Comment: If I remove the selection change listener then the double click listener works fine but it does not work when there is a selection change listener for the same tree. When I debugged the code I found out that, Object item = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement(); has an error wherein getFirstElement() returns null.

Comment: @Baz What is going wrong here?

Comment: @greg-449 What is going wrong here?

Comment: @user3354299 Which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: Object item = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();

Comment: getFirstElement() returns null.

Comment: The selection is empty for some reason

Comment: My other classes have the same code for double click listener and selection change listener on the same tree and it works fine, but in this class it throws an assertion failed exception, What could be the possible reasons for this kind of exception? Could u please tell me few possible reasons so that I can look into it?

Comment: I work on eclipse and when I debugged the code the selection does not return empty for selection change listener but it returns empty for only double click listener. If I remove the code for selection change listener then the double click listener works fine. I'm stuck here can u please get me out of it as I'm relatively new to these concepts, and I'm not aware of such exception.

Comment: @user3354299 If you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e., something we can copy+paste and run, then we might be able to help you. Otherwise it's nearly impossible for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hello All, I have an issue, Double-click works fine on the tree items but even When I press CTRL + M the tree items expand\collapse but I don't want this to happen, What's the reason behind this CTRL+M functionality?